# Sluggish desktop/Unity performance on ThinkPad Edge

Tags: unity, 12.10, thinkpad, cpu, ram

Fresh (1 week old) install of Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit version on a ThinkPad Edge 15, specs as follows:

[System specs (site wouldn't let me hotlink the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPDDZ.png)

I think the swap is about 2GB but can't remember how to check.

Problems encountered:

- General slow desktop performance; switching tabs in Chrome can take 5-10 seconds, windows frequently stop responding, fading to a translucent grey before coming back to life
- Super button takes 2-3 seconds to load Dash on fresh boot, but with basic programs (Chrome, Thunderbird) open after a few minutes then takes up to 1:30 to open up.
- Trying to restart the system, closing about half of the open programs crashed them
- Loading the system driver update window caused a crazy bug where the every time I switched back to the System Settings window it would try to open whatever icon was selected again, like the Return keypress event was repeating.
- Staying in any one program for a while tends to improve that program; staying in Chrome tab switching now takes under 1s, but switching away and back causes slowness.
- Opening system monitor seems to show compiz taking ~25% cpu usage even when not much stuff is going on. Sadly we have a dead/alive cat situation too, as system monitor also seems to sit at 15-20% cpu usage when monitoring anything else.

As an additional point, taking measurements just now showed Thunderbird at a ridiculous 565MB memory usage; previously it only ever hovered at about 200MB. Maybe not the problem, but may be related.

In case it helps anyone, here's my [Xorg.0.log file](http://pastebin.com/WtpyL56P). There's some mention of the graphics card right near the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot I'd never posted an answer on here or accepted one. I eventually solved this problem by replacing unity with gnome 2, all  performance issues vanished pretty much straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try the latest intel drivers from here: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa but this might as well make things even worse.

Comment: Is that done by adding the PPA and then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`? What do I do if this makes things worse, or not better?